# Error when compiling Bootstrap SASS files

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I've set up gulp to handle my Bootstrap template compilation:

```
gulp.task('sass', function() {
  return gulp.src('app/assets/sass/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/assets/css'))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({
      stream: true
    }));
});
```

My SASS main theme.scss file looks like:

```
@import "helpers/variables"; // custom variables    
@import "../bootstrap/sass/bootstrap"; // original Bootstrap files
@import "pages/index"; // custom styles
```

The problem is when I overwrite original Bootstrap variables in `helpers/variables`, e.g.:

```
// Variables

$navbar-height: 100px;
```

I get the following error:

> Error: File to import not found or unreadable: helpers/variables.

However, saving the main `main.scss` without any changes after I get the error message fixes the issue so the compilation goes as it should. Any ideas?

PS: My scss file tree is as below:

```
/assets/bootstrap/sass/_bootstrap.scss
/assets/sass/helpers/_variables.scss
/assets/sass/pages/_index.scss
/assets/sass/theme.scss
```

Answer (score 0):

bootstrap.scss is looking for the file helpers/_variables.scss relative to its own path. Edit bootstrap.scss to have your own _variables.scss file path.

As a note, (there is no right or wrong way to do this) I find it helpful to set up sass themes using frameworks in this manner:

```
src/
├── scss/
│   ├── my-theme/
│   │   ├── my-theme.scss
│   │   ├── _components.scss (and so on)
│   │   └── _new-variables.scss (a modified copy of bootstrap's)
│   └── vendor/
│       └── bootstrap/ (unaltered, for easier upgrading)
|           ├── bootstrap.scss
|           ├── _alerts.scss (and so on)
|           └── variables.scss
└─── main.scss
```

And main.scss looks like this:

```
// Core variables and mixins
@import "my-theme/new-variables";
@import "bootstrap/mixins";

// Reset and dependencies
@import "bootstrap/normalize";
@import "bootstrap/print";
@import "bootstrap/glyphicons";

// Core CSS
@import "bootstrap/scaffolding";
@import "bootstrap/type";
@import "bootstrap/code";

... the rest of boostrap stuff here ...

// Custom Theme 
@import "my-theme/my-theme";
```

Comment: I am afraid I didn't explain the question quite clear. I do not alter _bootstrap.scss at all (I prefer to keep all the vendor files intact). Instead, I include it as it is in my custom theme.scss, and prepend helpers/_variables.scss right before the imported _bootstrap.scss (which imports its own _variables.scss) to overwrite the `!default` variables there.

Comment: In fact, everything works like a charm except that I get an error message when trying to save my custom `hepers/_variables.scss`. Clicking to save any other custom `.scss` file in my `/sass` folder compiles the files (which is OK for me now, but I really wonder what's going on).